# Where can I get authentication token for aws get-current-user?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to figure out what's the current user for aws s3?  I found this command line online:[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/workdocs/get-current-user.html]

```
get-current-user
--authentication-token <value>
[--cli-input-json <value>]
[--generate-cli-skeleton <value>]
```

But this command line requires authetication token.  Where can I find it or is there better solution for me to get the current user for aws s3?

Comment: If you have no authorization token then there is no user.  Can you elaborate a bit on what you're trying to do?

Comment: @stdunbar, I think I have the authorization token, but I don't know where to find it.  Will it be in the aws console?

Comment: A token will be made of two parts, an access key and a secret key.  This information is usually stored in your home directory under the `.aws` directory.  If you have not explicitly set these up then they don't exist.  To create the keys, see the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_access-keys.html) for details.

Comment: `--authentication-token` here is a WorkDocs token.  Please start your question by explaining the original problem you were trying to solve, rather than how you are trying to solve it, because your attempted solution may be  off track. To find the "current user" in most cases, the correct commands are `aws iam get-user` or `aws sts get-caller-identity`.